# What function will be able to describe the distance between all perpendicular rays leaving a circle and hitting a parabola?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If I have a circle and parabola at the origin (very general)
$$
\text{p}\left(x\right):=a x^2 \\
\text{c}\left(x\right):=r-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}+b
$$

I want to know how I can apply Calculus techniques to determine the distance of all rays extended from the circle when they hit the parabola under it.

Will I be able to formulate a function that can describe what I am trying to explain?

Plot of what I mean:

[Plot of what I am trying to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BFr6.png)

Comment: You know the center of the circle. So for a ray with angle $\theta$ with the $y$-axis, you know the slope of the ray is $\tan(90^0 + \theta)$ (rays in the first quadrant). You also know a point that the rays pass through - center of the circle. Equating the equation of the ray and of the parabola, you should get the locus of the points you want.

Comment: @MathLover can you see my answer?? It looks like I've done everything correctly, but can you tell me if its the "best" way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I actually got the answer, it wasn't too bad, but please comment if you think I can "optimise" anything.

So firstly, any ray from the centre of the circle will be perpendicular to the circle. The tangent of the circle will always be:

$$\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{r^2-x_1^2}}$$
where $x_1$ is the x-value along the circle.

The line that is perpendicular to that tangent will be in the form:
$$ y=-\frac{\sqrt{r^2-x_1^2}}{x_1} x+c$$
Using the center of the circle as the "common point" (since we want a perpendicular ray) to solve for $c$ gives the following:

$$\text{d}\left(x\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{r^2-x_1^2}}{x_1} x+r+b$$
Note: the center of the circle is just $y=r + b$.

Then to find where the line intersects the parabola, just set both equations equal to each other.
$$
\text{p}\left(x\right)=\text{d}\left(x\right) \\
a x^2 = -\frac{\sqrt{r^2-x_1^2}}{x_1} x+r+b \\
\text{Solve polynomial (use positive value)} \\
x_2=\frac{-\sqrt{r^2-x_1^2}+\sqrt{4 a b x_1^2+4 a r x_1^2+r^2-x_1^2}}{2 a x_1}
$$
$x_2$ is the parabola intercept.

Now use the arc length formula and obtain equation in terms of $x_1$:

Using $x$ instead of $x_1$, we get:
$$\text{D}\left(x\right)=-\frac{\frac{r}{x}\left(2ax^{2}+\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}-\sqrt{r^{2}+x^{2}\left(4a\left(b+r\right)-1\right)}\right)}{2ax}$$

[Graph of the distance between the two curves at each x-value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FGYc.png)

Comment: I checked till parabola intercept $x_2$ and it looks fine. I did not follow the last part. Just as a side note, intuitively it seems would be simpler in polar coordinates.

Comment: @MathLover Yeah sorry, I'm not too confident with polar coordinates, but will definitely look into it next time! thanks!